# Is there any good book about the history of electricity?

Tags: electricity, resource-recommendation

Electricity history starting from William Gilbert in the 17th century.

Comment: Good for what? Until when? Wikipedia has a long list of book references for the history of electromagnetism article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_electromagnetic_theory#Bibliography Google search produces another one https://www.google.com/#q=history+of+electricity&tbm=bks

Comment: Refine your question. What do you already know about the history of electricity? Are you 13 or 30 with a PhD in a science? It's hard for anyone to recommend a book on such a big subject given zero detail on the recommendee. The first [dozen or so results here](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=history+of+electricity) are rated, and look terribly cheap. I've read none, except for that one about Tesla by Carlson toward the bottom. It was fairly entertaining, but not much new information, at least to me.

Comment: You can see : John Heilbron, [Electricity in the 17th and 18th Centuries: A Study of Early Modern Physics](https://books.google.it/books?id=UlTLRUn1sy8C&printsec=frontcover) (1979 - also Dover reprint).

Comment: why the downvote - this is a good question

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is:
https://archive.org/details/historyoftheorie00whitrich
A history of the theories of aether and electricity : from the age of Descartes to the close of the nineteenth century
by Whittaker, E. T.
It also contains history of optics, quantum mechanics and relativity.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Whittaker's book.